# deleted linux Mint from Win 8.1 dual-boot and cannot reinstall linux now

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

Until yesterday I had a dual-boot of Windows 8.1 with linux Mint 17.2 Rafaella Cinnamon 64bit.

Via the terminal I deleted something that I shouldn't and then when I rebooted the PC, linux stuck at the Mint logo. So I decided to delete the linux. In Windows I deleted the linux partition restarted the PC and a GNU prompt would appear and I couldn't load windows.As a solution i found two ways to delete gnu and be able to load windows normally.

The first one included using the Windows installation disk go to repair open CMD and type /bootrec.exe fixmbr, /bootrec.exe /fixboot (tried it several times with different order) didn't work (GNU was still there). Then I found this [How to boot windows after uninstalling ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/681379/how-to-boot-windows-after-uninstalling-ubuntu), which apparently removed GNU, since the PC boots Windows. After that Windows work fine. Now when I boot linux from live DVD, the screen says *could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi" :14*. Also when I want to install linux alongside windows, it doesn't recognise that the HDD has another OS. I really need to install linux again so what can i do? If I select something else for install will it affect windows 8.1?

Comment: New problem now i reinstalled linux mint in EFI mode as my custom installation of windows is.At the end of the install when i was told to restart an error occured something with monitor i think.I did forced shut down,started the pc grub showed and i logged to windows.Then i restarted the pc and grub was gone,now it boots directly to windows.What can i do?

Comment: I'd boot from the live CD(/DVD/USB) and install GRUB manually.

Comment: thanks for your answer can you provide more information?

Comment: i found the solution in this http://www.tweaking4all.com/os-tips-and-tricks/uefi-dual-boot-windows81-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my situation was found in http://www.tweaking4all.com/os-tips-and-tricks/uefi-dual-boot-windows81-ubuntu/